# Python, Selenium. Successfully initialized webdriver but couldn't open a web page because "there is no attribute called get"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I imported selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Initialized chrome webdriver as browser

```
browser = webdriver.chrome
```

But when I try to open a new tab I get a error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oOYW.png)

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you haven't created the browser object use below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver =webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")


driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

you just referenced the method you should trigger and call it by passing arguments